# SOLR - How to handle AND clause between 2 multivalue fields

Tags: solr

How would we use AND clause in the SOLR query between 2 fields those are multiple value fields?

For example; following is the picture of database table

JobseekerID        CompanyID        Email Sent On
===========     ===========    ==============

123                         ABC               22-Jul-2011

123                              XYZ               01-Jul-2011

Now in Sql, if i query

Where CompanyID = "ABC" AND EmailSentOn > 14-Jul-2011               (It will return TRUE)

Where CompanyID = "XYZ" AND EmailSentOn > 14-Jul-2011               (It will return FALSE)

How would we handle it in SOLR? Following is the picture of my SOLR Collection, how i am storing the data

{int name="jobseekerid"}123{/int}

.....................

.....................

.....................

{arr name="CompanyID"}

```
   {str}ABC{/str}

   {str}XYZ{/str}
```

{/arr}

{arr name="EmailSentOn"}

```
   {str}2011-07-22T17:44:00Z{/str}

   {str}2011-07-01T05:10:00Z{/str}
```

{/arr}

How can i query in the SOLR Now for Jobseeker 123. Because for SOLR there is not any relation between CompanyID and EmailSentON. It takes them two separate entities.

When we will query Company ID is "ABC" and EmailSentOn >= 14-July-2011 it will return TRUE and when we will say CompanyID is "XYZ" and EmailSentOn >= 14-July-2011 it will again return TRUE because SOLR will see, does company ID "XYZ" exist and *any* date in the 'email sent on' is greater than 14-July then it will return true.

But we need it to check if the CompanyID "XYZ" then the company XYZ date is greater than 14-july or not. Which is not, because XYZ sent email date is "01-Jul". So it should return false for that.

I hope you get my point. Can anyone please guide me how would we handle this in SOLR?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with the definition of the schema - you don't actually have multiValued data!  Instead, you should just have two separate indexed documents with single values for CompanyId and EmailSentOn.  Then when you search by date you get back just the contents of one document or another and don't have the results jumbled as you do now.

Comment: You mean we have to repeat jobseekerID even it is Unique Key in the schema. Let me explain little about my database structure please. It is a resume management system. We have many relational tables with Jobseeker those have one to many relation. I followed my database structure in my schema. JobseekerID is unique in my schema and all the relational table data is in multi value fields. My database has more than 700,000 Jobseekers. Now if i follow your suggestion then my each jobseeker would have avg. 1000 relational entries and my collection would have approx. 700000 X 1000 = 700000000 Doc.

Comment: Do you believe this is the *best* way to handle this? Please suggest me any other way to handle this.

Comment: Keep in mind that Solr is best used as a full-text search webservice and not a relational database.  If you're mimicking a MySQL schema, it's very likely you're doing something inefficient/incorrect.  You should figure out what you're searching for, configure a Solr schema that lets you accomplish that task, and leave the relational stuff to MySQL.  If you have 700K users, my answer would be that you should have far less than 1000 docs/user, unless there are truly 1000 pieces of unique searchable information per user, which seems unlikely.